# Webcam streaming - Stream Images to Image Control at variable intervals?

Tags: c#, image, video-streaming, webcam

I'm having a problem where users with a slow connection aren't getting my image feed properly.

i'm sending them new images every second to a picturebox inside an Ajax Update panel, using an Ajax Timer.

so if their connection is really slow, one image doesnt load fully before the next one comes in, so they never get the whole picture...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use image OnLoad event in JavaScript. In other words, do not load a new image until the last one is not completely loaded.

Probably you shouldn't use Update panel. The image tag (including its size, look and position) remains the same; it's the source which changes. Rather than updating everything, I suggest to do the following *on client side*:

1. At the beginning, load the first image (without Update panel).
2. Add a listener to the `OnLoad` event to `<img />` on client side.
3. When the picture is fully loaded, reload it by querying the server for a more recent picture. For example, you may consider having an ASP.NET page `Camera.aspx` which serves the most recent pictures grabbed from the camera. To be sure the page is really queried, change the `src` property of `<img />` element to `Camera.aspx?t=1`,  `Camera.aspx?t=2`, etc.

*On server side* (so no JavaScript here), the grabbed images are stored in database, so `Camera.aspx` will query for the last stored record, retrieve it and send directly to the client (specifying appropriate `Response.ContentType` and using `Response.OutputStream`).

To achieve better visual response, you may also want to consider using two image elements in parallel: when the first one is loading, the second is displayed, and vice versa. It *might* be better, but I'm not sure, so test before choosing the appropriate method.

Comment: that sounds like a great idea! i dont know much about javascript though... so how would i get the next image url from the database in the OnLoad event?

Comment: @Faizan Kazi: see the modified answer. Best regards.

Comment: thanks!! i'm so sorry for the late response but your answer was pretty much perfect.. i've just got one little detail to clear up... how do i assign the image from Camera.aspx to the image? thats kinda like a web service right?

Comment: @Faizan Kazi: if I understand correctly your question, you can simply do the following: `<img src="Camera.aspx" alt="..." />`.

Comment: sorry, let me rephrase... how do i get camera.aspx to serve the image? get the image from file/database and do a Response.BinaryWrite?

Comment: Rather use `this.Response.OutputStream` to get the stream of `Camera.aspx`, then stream the content directly by writing to this output stream. Don't forget to set `this.Response.BufferOutput` to `false`.